# How to write query joining the columns from variable no of subqueries (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, join, subquery, union

I have following MySQL query which gives the result I wish however I'm sure there are far better ways to achieve this. Furthermore there is a variable number of columns (R1, R2, ...) to be shown depending on wether there are scores (SCORELINKS, SCORERECHTS) for the specific round (RONDEID = 1, 2, ...).

What can I do to achieve that and tidy the code?

```
SELECT KLASSE K, IF(MV="M","Dhr.", "Mw.") T, VOORLETTERS V, TUSSENVOEGSEL T, ACHTERNAAM Naam, NAAM Club, R1, R2, TOTAAL Totaal
FROM LID, CLUB, DEELNEMER,
    (
    SELECT A.COMPDNID, A.R R1, B.R R2, A.R+B.R Totaal
    FROM
        (
        SELECT COMPDNID, SCORELINKS+SCORERECHTS AS R 
        FROM SCORE
        WHERE RONDEID=1) A, 
        (
        SELECT COMPDNID, SCORELINKS+SCORERECHTS AS R 
        FROM SCORE
        WHERE RONDEID=2) B
    WHERE A.COMPDNID = B.COMPDNID) S
WHERE LID.CLUBID=CLUB.CLUBID AND S.COMPDNID=DEELNEMER.COMPDNID AND DEELNEMER.BONDSNUMMER=LID.BONDSNUMMER AND KLASSE !=  "AA"
ORDER BY KLASSE, TOTAAL DESC
LIMIT 0,500
```

Code rewritten in join-style in response to first comment (with same query result):

```
select K, G, V, T, Naam, rondeid, R1, R2, R3, R4, R5, R6, R1+R2+R3+R4+R5+R6 as Totaal 
from (
    select K, G, V, T, L.Naam, rondeid, coalesce(R1,0) R1, coalesce(R2,0) R2, coalesce(R3,0) R3, coalesce(R4,0) R4, coalesce(R5,0) R5, coalesce(R6,0) R6 
    from (
        select clubid, naam from club) as C
            join (select clubid, bondsnummer, if(mv="M", "Dhr.", "Mw.") as G, voorletters as V, tussenvoegsel as T, achternaam as Naam from lid) as L on C.clubid=L.clubid
            join (select bondsnummer, klasse as K, compdnid from deelnemer) as D on L.bondsnummer=D.bondsnummer
            left join (select compdnid, rondeid, scorelinks+scorerechts as R1 from score where rondeid=1) as R1 on D.compdnid=R1.compdnid
            left join (select compdnid, scorelinks+scorerechts as R2 from score where rondeid=2) as R2 on R1.compdnid=R2.compdnid
            left join (select compdnid, scorelinks+scorerechts as R3 from score where rondeid=3) as R3 on R2.compdnid=R3.compdnid
            left join (select compdnid, scorelinks+scorerechts as R4 from score where rondeid=4) as R4 on R3.compdnid=R4.compdnid
            left join (select compdnid, scorelinks+scorerechts as R5 from score where rondeid=5) as R5 on R4.compdnid=R5.compdnid
            left join (select compdnid, scorelinks+scorerechts as R6 from score where rondeid=6) as R6 on R5.compdnid=R6.compdnid

    where K = "A" or K = "B" or K = "C") as S
order by K, Totaal desc
```

Example result:

Issue: 
number of R columns may vary. The last column must always show the total of all the R columns.

```
K T    V  Naam               Club            Rl  R2  Totaal
A Dhr. B. Woordes            De Eendracht    259 260 519
A Dhr. W. Ros.               Val Umme        247 251 498
A Dhr. J. Schreurs           De Eendracht    243 246 489
A Dhr. E. Grevink            `t Wieskamp     232 256 488
A Dhr. J. Klein Gebbink      De Vrijheid     239 245 484
A Dhr. J. Kobus              Val Umme        230 250 480
A Dhr. P. Nijmolen           Val Umme        218 255 473
A Mw.  A. den Boer-Gerritsen Tot Ons Plezier 227 241 468
A Mw.  J. Dam van            Val Umme        231 235 466
```

Here are the definitions of the tables involved in the query:

[image]

Raw data:
LID:

[image]

DEELNEMER:

[image]

CLUB:

[image]

SCORE:

[image]

Comment: Please learn to write queries using explicit, ANSI `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: I don't undertand the question. What's the problem with the query you have. If you're looking for commentary on the style and suggestions for improvement, codereview.stackexhange.com is the proper place.

Comment: could you provide more samples of raw source data and expected query result?

Comment: I added example output and more info on the issue, please refer to question

Comment: I rewrote the query using joins in response to comment from Bamar.
However original issue (variable number of R-columns and/or how to deal with null values in determining total of values containing null-values) is still to be solved